# How to route packets between private networks on linux?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

[image]

Hello! I need to connect 3 networks.

Here is what I did:

for the "left" host

```
ip route add default via 192.168.26.4
ip route show
default via 192.168.26.4 dev enp0s3
```

for the "right" host

```
ip route add default via 192.168.27.4
ip route show
default via 192.168.27.4 dev enp0s3
```

for the "left" router

```
ip route add default via 10.26.0.1
ip route add 192.168.26.0/24 via 192.168.26.1
ip route show
default via 10.26.0.1 dev enp0s8
192.168.26.0/24 via 192.168.26.1 dev enp0s3
```

for the "right" router

```
ip route add default via 10.26.0.2
ip route add 192.168.27.0/24 via 192.168.27.1
ip route show
default via 10.26.0.2 dev enp0s8
192.168.27.0/24 via 192.168.27.1 dev enp0s3
```

Also I enabled ip forwarding on both routers (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`)

And now I can ping the closest router to the host. i.e. from the left host I can ping left router by both ip addresses (ping 192.168.26.1 and ping 10.26.0.1), but I can't ping the next router or host (destination host unreachable). Same happens with the right host.
Also I can ping hosts from the closest router (from 192.168.27(6).1 I can ping 192.168.27(6).4). And I can ping from router to router by both addresses.
The problem is that I can't ping from host to host or even from host to the next router.

I think I did something wrong with the routes, but I don't know what exactly.
I was trying to change routes in routers to the neighbour ip (in the left router add route default via 10.24.0.2) but all that I get is `network is unreachable`.

Comment: Your problem is with the left router and right router. They obviously are not forwarding packets coming in from one interface and destined for the other. I think you need to ask this question in network engineering, specifying the name and model of your routers and what type of interfaces are connected to those slots.

Comment: Try telling the left host that the default route's gw is 192.168.26.1. Otherwise it won't know where to send packets destined beyond its local net.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick, in this case I can't ping neither the router nor the host. `ping 192.168.26.1 - connect: network is unreachable`

@MelBurslan, the routers are just fedora server and ubuntu server on virtualbox